# JAXB Unmarshalling: List of objects

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", name = "content")
@XmlType(name = "course")
public class Course implements Resource

...

@XmlElementWrapper(name="subcourses")
@XmlElement(name="course")
List<Xlink> subcourses;         //!?
```

and Xlink class, which works fine in inline variable.

```
public class Xlink
{
    private String href;
    private String value;

    @XmlAttribute(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
    public String getHref()
    {
        return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String href)
    {
        this.href = href;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

for an XML input of

```
<atom:content atom:type="xml" xsi:type="course">
...
   <subcourses>
      <course xlink:href="course1">Some course</course>
      <course xlink:href="course2">other course</course>
```

And subcourses refuses to be unmarshalled (without any exception being thrown).

Note: MOXy is unfortunately not an option.

Edit: new marshalled object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:content xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <code>SOME CODE</code>
    <name>name</name>
    <subcourses>
        <course ns2:href="Some href">some value</course>
        <course ns2:href="sdsdg">sdfhdfhdhdh</course>
    </subcourses>
</ns3:content>
```

Edit2: after some experimentation with unmarshalling and marshalling a test object I have discovered that I need to define xmlns namespace in the header of the content to match `xlink:href=` like `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` the problem is that I am getting the Course element from inside a wrapper class that is parsed out by resteasy. Thus the resulting class does not carry over the namespace information.

I somehow need to force JAXB to understand that `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` applies to the course elements, but after an hour of google I am at a loss.

Edit3: I am getting my object from

https://github.com/jirutka/atom-jaxb/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/jirutka/atom/jaxb/Entry.java

which is used on the server counterpart. Which in turn is a part of

https://github.com/jirutka/atom-jaxb/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/jirutka/atom/jaxb/Feed.java

Relevant parts of my unmarshalling code are:

```
Feed f = r.readEntity(Feed.class);
out.addAll(unmarshaller.Unmarshal(f.getEntries(), clazz));
```

where `r` is a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`. And the unmarshaller

```
public List<T> Unmarshal(List<Entry> entries, Class clazz)
{
    List<T> out = new ArrayList<T>();
    T instance;
    for (Entry e : entries)
    {
        try
        {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
            Unmarshaller unmarsh = context.createUnmarshaller();
            instance = (T) unmarsh.unmarshal((Node) e.getContent());
```

Since this is my first tangle with this technology, it is entirely possible that this code is 'wtf'.

Comment: What do you mean by 'refuses to be unmarshalled'? Just delivers an empty list?

Comment: Yes everytime 0 items.

Comment: Can you provide more details on where the XML fragment you are unmarshalling comes from?

Answer (score 9):

When you annotate the field (instance variable) be sure to put `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", name = "content")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Course implements Resource {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "subcourses")
    @XmlElement(name = "course")
    List<Xlink> subcourses;

}
```

Then make sure your XML input is correctly namespace qualified.  Your input document should look something like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<atom:content xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <code>SOME CODE</code>
    <name>name</name>
    <subcourses>
        <course xlink:href="Some href">some value</course>
        <course xlink:href="sdsdg">sdfhdfhdhdh</course>
    </subcourses>
</atom:content>
```

With my updated `Course` class,  your `Xlink` class and a properly namespace qualified XML document the following demo code worked perfectly for me.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Course.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17766166/input.xml");
        Course course = (Course) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(course, System.out);
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

> Edit2: after some experimentation with unmarshalling and marshalling a
>   test object I have discovered that I need to define xmlns namespace in
>   the header of the content to match xlink:href= like
>   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" the problem is that I am
>   getting the Course element from inside a wrapper class that is parsed
>   out by resteasy. Thus the resulting class does not carry over the
>   namespace information.

The best place to fix your issue is where you extract the fragment you wish to unmarhal.  Below is a strategy you can use with StAX.

***input.xml***

Below is a sample XML document where the namespace information is defined above the fragment you wish to unmarshal.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <bar>
        <atom:content>
            <code>SOME CODE</code>
            <name>name</name>
            <subcourses>
                <course xlink:href="Some href">some value</course>
                <course xlink:href="sdsdg">sdfhdfhdhdh</course>
            </subcourses>
        </atom:content>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

***Demo***

Below we will use a StAX `XMLStreamReader` to navigate to the target fragment.  We will have our JAXB implementation unmarshal this fragment.  This way all the namespace information is preserved.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Course.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("src/forum17766166/input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);
        while(xsr.hasNext()) {
            if(xsr.isStartElement() && "content".equals(xsr.getLocalName())) {
                break;
            }
            xsr.next();
        }

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Course course = (Course) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(course, System.out);
    }

}
```

***Output***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:content xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <subcourses>
        <course ns2:href="Some href">some value</course>
        <course ns2:href="sdsdg">sdfhdfhdhdh</course>
    </subcourses>
</ns3:content>
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

If you can't produce a better XML fragment as described in UPDATE #1, below is how you could fix the XML fragment you currently have.

***NamespaceFilter***

You could use a SAX `XMLFilter` to fix up your XML document.

```
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;

public class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {

    private static final String ATOM_URI = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
    private static final String XLINK_URI = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if("atom:content".equals(qName)) {
            super.startElement(ATOM_URI, "content", qName, atts);
        } else if("course".equals(qName))  {
            AttributesImpl modifiedAtts = new AttributesImpl();
            modifiedAtts.addAttribute(XLINK_URI, "href", "xlink:href", null, atts.getValue(0));
            super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, modifiedAtts);
        } else {
            super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if("atom:content".equals(qName)) {
            super.endElement(ATOM_URI, "content", qName);
        } else {
            super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        }
    }

}
```

***Demo***

Below is how you can leverage the `XmlFilter` with JAXB:

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Course.class);

        // Create the XMLFilter
        XMLFilter filter = new NamespaceFilter();

        // Set the parent XMLReader on the XMLFilter
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        filter.setParent(xr);

        // Set UnmarshallerHandler as ContentHandler on XMLFilter
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller
                .getUnmarshallerHandler();
        filter.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);

        // Parse the XML
        InputSource xml = new InputSource("src/forum17766166/input.xml");
        filter.parse(xml);
        Course course = (Course) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(course, System.out);
    }

}
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/applying-namespace-during-jaxb-unmarshal.html

---

**UPDATE #3**

Below is a simplified version of your example code where everything works.  Maybe there is something different in your code it will help you find.

**Entry**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry<T> {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "atomInlineOtherContent")
    private T content;

    public T getContent() {
        return content;
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <atom:content>
        <code>SOME CODE</code>
        <name>name</name>
        <subcourses>
            <course xlink:href="Some href">some value</course>
            <course xlink:href="sdsdg">sdfhdfhdhdh</course>
        </subcourses>
    </atom:content>
</atom:entry>
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entry.class, Course.class);

        // Unmarshal Entry
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17766166/input.xml");
        Entry entry = (Entry) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        // Unmarshal Course
        Node contentNode = (Node) entry.getContent();
        Course course = (Course) unmarshaller.unmarshal(contentNode);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(course, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:content xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <subcourses>
      <course ns1:href="Some href">some value</course>
      <course ns1:href="sdsdg">sdfhdfhdhdh</course>
   </subcourses>
</ns0:content>
```

Comment: Trying to implement this, there is a problem. What I get from Response is a Node object of already parsed XML nodes. And I cant force the readEntity() which calls JAXB provider to give me a String object. And if I try to cast it into Course it throws ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to Course. I am sure I am doing something somewhere wrong, but don't know what.

Comment: @Meltea - You could unmarshal the `Node` object.

Comment: No, adding `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` just gives lots of errors like `Class has two properties of the same name`, while without it code works fine, with an excetion of lists